# Using the simplified print option on Firefox via Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, helium

I'm trying to access a set of links and download them using the simplified print format on Firefox using Selenium. My current code downloads the webpage as a pdf in the original form but I need to get it in the simplified form.

Here is my current code snippet which downloads the pdf in the original format.

```
from time import sleep

from helium import start_firefox
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
options.set_preference("print.printer_Mozilla_Save_to_PDF.print_to_file", True)
options.set_preference("print_printer", "Mozilla Save to PDF")
options.set_preference("print.use_simplify_page", True) # Does not seem to download in the simplified form

driver = start_firefox("https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/selenium/", options=options, headless = True)

driver.execute_script("window.print();")
sleep(10)  # Found that a little wait is needed for the print to be rendered otherwise the file will be corrupted

driver.quit()
```

The format I'm trying to get it in can be viewed by opening the link (https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/nutritionsource/selenium/) on firefox and using the print option. Under format please select "simplified".

Is there any way this can be done in the required format?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! How would I go about checking with Mozilla, my apologies I'm new to this.